# Changing the selected text in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I would like to change the selected value of a dropdown onclick of a button. There are a few dropdowns in a div with class = '.WHERE', I want to append a parenthesis to the first dropdown and to the second to last dropdown
The button calls this function:

```
//add parenthesis to the first child, and to the second to last child
    function addParens(){
      var len = $(".WHERE").children('div > select').length;
      len -= 1;

      var firstDropdown = $('.WHERE').children().first(); //the first child
      var lastDropdown = $('.WHERE').children().eq(len);  //the second to last child
//attempting here to append left parenthesis to the first dropdown
          var text = firstDropdown.val(); //the old selected option
          text = '(' + text; //new text with left parenthesis
          console.log(text);  //prints out correctly
          firstDropdown.text(text); //tried ,doesn't work
          var firstId = firstDropdown.attr('id'); //grab id firstDropdown
          $('#'+firstId).val(text); //doesn't work by grabbing id first
          firstDropdown.val(text); //also tried this, doesn't work




    }
```

Afterwards if I print firstDropwdown.val() it prints null, and the dropdown has nothing selected.
here is a sample of what one of the dropdown looks like, it is created dynamically  
 
[image]

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/27nskcf5/

Comment: YES! that works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function addParens() {
  var len = $(".WHERE").children('div > select').length;
  len -= 1;

  var children = $('.WHERE').children();
  var firstDropdown = children.first().find("option:selected"); //the first child
  var lastDropdown = children.eq(len).find("option:selected"); //the second to last child
  firstDropdown.text('(' + firstDropdown.text() + ')');
  lastDropdown.text('(' + lastDropdown.text() + ')');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="WHERE">
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option>Article.Author</option>
    <option>Article.Editor</option>
    <option>Article.Publisher</option>
    <option>Article.Title</option>
    <option>Article.BookTitle</option>
    <option>Article.Year</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option>Article.Author</option>
    <option>Article.Editor</option>
    <option>Article.Publisher</option>
    <option>Article.Title</option>
    <option>Article.BookTitle</option>
    <option>Article.Year</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option>Article.Author</option>
    <option>Article.Editor</option>
    <option>Article.Publisher</option>
    <option>Article.Title</option>
    <option>Article.BookTitle</option>
    <option>Article.Year</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option>Article.Author</option>
    <option>Article.Editor</option>
    <option>Article.Publisher</option>
    <option>Article.Title</option>
    <option>Article.BookTitle</option>
    <option>Article.Year</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button onClick="addParens();">
DO IT
</button>
```